# RDS Farm black screen at logon (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

Randomly, connections are no longer possible on the RDS with the following pattern:
"Connect to RDS > Enter login/password > Long load on "Secure connection" > Black screen and RDP close"

Users can no longer login, either for a new connection or for a session that has already been opened, but in "disconnected" state. The only solution is to restart the RDS which is blocked.

We had this problem on our 3 RDS (RDS01, RDS02 and RDS03).
One day, we had the problem on RDS02 and in order to reconnect users we decided to open connections on RDS03, but only 1 hour later RDS03 had the same problem.
The problem occurs at random times and sometimes after several days, sometimes after just a few hours, sometimes it's the same RDS several times in a row, sometimes it's one after the other.
At first, we thought it was isolated to a single RDS, but this is clearly not the case.

In the server logs, the event "ID 4005 Winlogon" is triggered.
We haven't made any configuration changes, GPOs or added any software that might explain this change in behavior.
Restarting the TermService (Remote Desktop Service) and SessionEnv (Remote Desktop Service Configuration) services does not correct the problem. RDS server must be restarted.

The 3 RDS are up to date on Windows Update, the farm has been in service since 2018 and there has never been this problem.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (1) Do you use a third-party security service such as Webroot? (2) According to Microsoft, this might be a resources problem, so next time it happens please do [this](https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-for-Business/Users-unable-to-login-to-terminal-server-with-Webroot-installed/m-p/257946#M3644) to debug.

Comment: Hi, we use SentinelOne as third-party security service. Your link does not work.